# Django Edit Profile View not saving new email value

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am (attempting to) implement the ability for a user to edit and update their email address on their profile page. I am getting no errors when doing this end to end but the new email is not being saved to the DB.

Everything seems to be working, even the redirect to the profile page in the edit_profile function, but the save() doesn't seem to be working, the users email doesn't update and when I am redirected back to the profile page, the email is still the current value.

Thanks!

Model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
is_pro = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_golfer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

Form

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.Form):
email = forms.EmailField(
    label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-field'}))
```

View

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
        
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        user.save()
    return redirect("typeA", username=user.username)
else:
    form = EditProfileForm()
return render(request, "registration/edit_profile.html", {'form': form})
```

URLS

```
urlpatterns = [
path('type_a_signup/', ASignUpView.as_view(), name='a_signup'),
path('type_b_signup/', BSignUpView.as_view(), name='b_signup'),
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('password_reset', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
path('typea/<username>/', typeA, name='typeA'),
path('typeb/<username>/', typeB, name='typeB'),
path('login_success/', login_success, name='login_success'),
path('edit_profile/', edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
]
```

Template

```
<div class="container">
<div class="form-container">
    <h2>Edit profile</h2>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            {{ form.email.label_tag }}
            <input type="text" class="form-control {% if form.email.errors %}is-invalid{% endif %}" id="id_email"
                name="email" value='{{ form.email.value|default:user.email }}'>
            {% if form.email.errors %}
            <div>{{ form.email.errors }}</div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set the `email` field of the object. You should set this with:

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
        user = request.user
        user.email = email  # 🖘 set the email field
        user.save()
        return redirect("typeA", username=user.username)
else:
    form = EditProfileForm()
return render(request, "registration/edit_profile.html", {'form': form})
```

You should only redirect in case the form is successful. If it is not, Django will *rerender* the form with the errors.

Comment: Couple quick questions if you have time. Why did you use user = request.user instead of user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id). I take your point about error handling, I am going to do that now once I get this working.

Comment: @StevieMadds: because that is a user model object, by doing `CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)`, you will make a *second* query to fetch what you already have: a `CustomUser` object that is the logged in user.